# How load and update large excel file >15MB using openpyxl without read_only = True

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am new to python, I was trying to load large excel file of size 15MB with 3 sheets/tab. I am trying to update 3rd tab. Since I need to update 3rd sheet, I was trying to load the excel with `openpyxl.load_workbook()` without read_only. My system got hung while loading could you please help. I dont want use `read_only=True`, because i want to edit the third sheet.

Thanks,

```py
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
meta_df = pd.read_csv('metafile')
file = 'file.xlsx'
book = load_workbook(file)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((wsh.title, wsh) for wsh in book.worksheets)
meta_df.to_excel(writer, 'meta_data', index=False, header=False, startrow=1)
writer.save()
```

Comment: How much memory does your system have? You could easily combine read-only and write-only modes here. Also, I don't the see the need for Pandas at all, just append the CSV rows directly to a worksheet.

Comment: My system has 8GB RAM, The sheet 'file.xlsx' is an excel template with 3 sheets say sheet1, sheet2 and meta_data. sheet1 and sheet2 has pivot tables that depended on meta_data. I just need to update the third tab 'meta_data' without removing existing header. So I am using meta_df.to_excel with header = False and startrow=1. but openpyxl's load_workbook doesnt work. Can this be achieved by combining read-only and write-only? could you please give me any reference or code i can refer?

Comment: How can we combine read only and write only mode for same workbook. Can you please refer to an example.